# LINQ DistinctBy with multiple fields does not contains a definitions for DistinctBy

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to add DistinctBy to four fields in this LINQ statement but I am getting some errors that does not contains a definitions for DistinctBy. Is there an class that I need to import?

```
    public IQueryable<TemplatesJoinAgent> GetTemplateAgentKeyDiseaseId(Guid? agentKey, Guid? diseaseId)
    {
        //Common part
        var TemplatesJoinAgent = (from t in UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Template>().Get()
                    join r in UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Regimen>().Get() on t.Id equals r.TemplateId
                    join rp in UnitOfWork.GetRepository<RegimenPart>().Get() on r.Id equals rp.RegimenId
                    join re in UnitOfWork.GetRepository<RegimenEntry>().Get() on rp.Id equals re.RegimenPartId
                    join a in UnitOfWork.GetRepository<Agent>().Get() on re.AgentVersionKey equals a.VersionKey
                    where t.IsCurrentVersion && t.Status==7 && a.IsCurrentVersion
                    select new TemplatesJoinAgent
                    {
                        Template = t,

                        Agent = a

                    });

        //Extra filters
        if (agentKey != null)
        {
            TemplatesJoinAgent = TemplatesJoinAgent.Where(o => o.Agent.VersionKey == agentKey);
        }
        if (diseaseId != null)
        {
            TemplatesJoinAgent = TemplatesJoinAgent.Where(o => o.Template.ExternalDiseaseId == diseaseId);
        }

        TemplatesJoinAgent = TemplatesJoinAgent.DistinctBy(x => t.DiseaseName).ToList();

        return TemplatesJoinAgent;
    }
```

Comment: DistinctBy is not part of the standard linq functions. You need to add a reference to [Morelinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) or some other framework that has this function.

Comment: Or you can have your own `DistinctBy` as extension: https://www.elevenwinds.com/blog/linq-distinctby-with-lambda-expression-parameter/. But if you are talking about framework-provided functionality, it is `Distinct()`. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Distinct__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by others, `DistinctBy` is not part of the standard LINQ functions. You can however add this function by implementing your own DistinctBy extension. Something like this sould do the job:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource,TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
        {
            var keys = new HashSet<TKey>();
            foreach (TSource item in source)
            {
                if (keys.Add(selector(item)))
                    yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```